# Jquery checkbox checked and unchecked issue between paggination

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

i dont why it is  working on current page only i want to work it on every page by default 
    when we check the check box in the header section only the check boxes present in that page are getting triggered unless we go to the previous pages.

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.2.2/css/dataTables.alphabetSearch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.2.2/js/dataTables.alphabetSearch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.6/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       //
```

Updates "Select all" control in a data table

```
function updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table){
   var $table             = table.table().node();
   var $chkbox_all        = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]', $table);
   var $chkbox_checked    = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', $table);
   var chkbox_select_all  = $('thead input[name="select_all"]', $table).get(0);

   If none of the checkboxes are checked

   if($chkbox_checked.length === 0){
      chkbox_select_all.checked = false;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
      }

   // If all of the checkboxes are checked
```

here i am trying to select checkboxs on select all it is selecting data of same page but not all page

```
   } else if ($chkbox_checked.length === $chkbox_all.length){
      chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
      }

   // If some of the checkboxes are checked
   } else {
      chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = true;
      }
   }
}

$(document).ready(function (){
   // Array holding selected row IDs
   var rows_selected = [];

   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'columnDefs': [{
         'targets': 0,
         'searchable':false,
         'orderable':false,
         'className': 'dt-body-center',


         'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
             return '<input type="checkbox">';
         }
      }],

 dom: 'Alfrtip',
   responsive: true,
      'order': [1, 'asc'],

             alphabetSearch: {
         column:1
      }, 
      'rowCallback': function(row, data, dataIndex){
         // Get row ID
         var rowId = data[0];

         // If row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
         if($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1){
            $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
            $(row).addClass('selected');
         }
      }
   });

   // Handle click on checkbox
   $('#example tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
      var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

      // Get row data
      var data = table.row($row).data();

      // Get row ID
      var rowId = data[0];

      // Determine whether row ID is in the list of selected row IDs 
      var index = $.inArray(data, rows_selected);

      // If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
      if(this.checked && index === -1){
         rows_selected.push(data);

      // Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
      } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1){
         rows_selected.splice(index, 1);
      }

      if(this.checked){
         $row.addClass('selected');
      } else {
         $row.removeClass('selected');
      }

      // Update state of "Select all" control
      updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);

      // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
      e.stopPropagation();
   });

   // Handle click on table cells with checkboxes
   $('#example').on('click', 'tbody td, thead th:first-child', function(e){
      $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
   });

   // Handle click on "Select all" control
   $('thead input[name="select_all"]', table.table().container()).on('click', function(e){
      if(this.checked){
         $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', table.table().container()).trigger('click');
      } else {
         $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked',table.table().container()).trigger('click');
      }

      // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
      e.stopPropagation();
   });

   // Handle table draw event
   table.on('draw', function(){
      // Update state of "Select all" control
      updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);
   });

    var arr = [];
   // Handle form submission event 
   $('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){
      var form = this;

       arr=[];
       var getRowValue="";

      // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
      $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
         // Create a hidden element 

        getRowValue= rowId;
        arr.push(getRowValue);
      });

 for (var i=0; i < arr.length ;i++){
       alert("Name: " + arr[i][1] + " Position:" + arr[i][2] + " Office: " + arr[i][3] + "Extn: " + arr[i][4], " StartDate:" + arr[i][5]);
    }



      // FOR DEMONSTRATION ONLY     

      // Output form data to a console     


        $('#printarr').text(arr);



      // Remove added elements
      $('input[name="id\[\]"]', form).remove();

      // Prevent actual form submission
      e.preventDefault();

   });


 });




    </script>
<body>

    <form id="frm-example" action="" method="POST">

    <table id="example" class="display select" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"></th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Position</th>
             <th>Office</th>
             <th>Extn.</th>
             <th>Start date</th>
             <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tfoot>
          <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Position</th>
             <th>Office</th>
             <th>Extn.</th>
             <th>Start date</th>
             <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
       </tfoot>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
               <td>System Architect</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>61</td>
               <td>2011/04/25</td>
               <td>$320,800</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>Garrett Winters</td>
               <td>Accountant</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>63</td>
               <td>2011/07/25</td>
               <td>$170,750</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>Ashton Cox</td>
               <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>66</td>
               <td>2009/01/12</td>
               <td>$86,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
               <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>2012/03/29</td>
               <td>$433,060</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>Airi Satou</td>
               <td>Accountant</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>33</td>
               <td>2008/11/28</td>
               <td>$162,700</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>6</td>
               <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
               <td>Integration Specialist</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>61</td>
               <td>2012/12/02</td>
               <td>$372,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>7</td>
               <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
               <td>Sales Assistant</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>59</td>
               <td>2012/08/06</td>
               <td>$137,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>8</td>
               <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
               <td>Integration Specialist</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>55</td>
               <td>2010/10/14</td>
               <td>$327,900</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>9</td>
               <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
               <td>Javascript Developer</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>39</td>
               <td>2009/09/15</td>
               <td>$205,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>Sonya Frost</td>
               <td>Software Engineer</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>23</td>
               <td>2008/12/13</td>
               <td>$103,600</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>11</td>
               <td>Jena Gaines</td>
               <td>Office Manager</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>30</td>
               <td>2008/12/19</td>
               <td>$90,560</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>12</td>
               <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
               <td>Support Lead</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>2013/03/03</td>
               <td>$342,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>13</td>
               <td>Charde Marshall</td>
               <td>Regional Director</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>36</td>
               <td>2008/10/16</td>
               <td>$470,600</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>14</td>
               <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
               <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>43</td>
               <td>2012/12/18</td>
               <td>$313,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>15</td>
               <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
               <td>Regional Director</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>19</td>
               <td>2010/03/17</td>
               <td>$385,750</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>16</td>
               <td>Michael Silva</td>
               <td>Marketing Designer</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>66</td>
               <td>2012/11/27</td>
               <td>$198,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>17</td>
               <td>Paul Byrd</td>
               <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>64</td>
               <td>2010/06/09</td>
               <td>$725,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>18</td>
               <td>Gloria Little</td>
               <td>Systems Administrator</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>59</td>
               <td>2009/04/10</td>
               <td>$237,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>19</td>
               <td>Bradley Greer</td>
               <td>Software Engineer</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>41</td>
               <td>2012/10/13</td>
               <td>$132,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>20</td>
               <td>Dai Rios</td>
               <td>Personnel Lead</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>35</td>
               <td>2012/09/26</td>
               <td>$217,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>21</td>
               <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
               <td>Development Lead</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>30</td>
               <td>2011/09/03</td>
               <td>$345,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>Yuri Berry</td>
               <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>40</td>
               <td>2009/06/25</td>
               <td>$675,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>23</td>
               <td>Caesar Vance</td>
               <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>21</td>
               <td>2011/12/12</td>
               <td>$106,450</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>24</td>
               <td>Doris Wilder</td>
               <td>Sales Assistant</td>
               <td>Sidney</td>
               <td>23</td>
               <td>2010/09/20</td>
               <td>$85,600</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>25</td>
               <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
               <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>47</td>
               <td>2009/10/09</td>
               <td>$1,200,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>26</td>
               <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
               <td>Developer</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>42</td>
               <td>2010/12/22</td>
               <td>$92,575</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>27</td>
               <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
               <td>Regional Director</td>
               <td>Singapore</td>
               <td>28</td>
               <td>2010/11/14</td>
               <td>$357,650</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>28</td>
               <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
               <td>Software Engineer</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>28</td>
               <td>2011/06/07</td>
               <td>$206,850</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>29</td>
               <td>Fiona Green</td>
               <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>48</td>
               <td>2010/03/11</td>
               <td>$850,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>30</td>
               <td>Shou Itou</td>
               <td>Regional Marketing</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>20</td>
               <td>2011/08/14</td>
               <td>$163,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>31</td>
               <td>Michelle House</td>
               <td>Integration Specialist</td>
               <td>Sidney</td>
               <td>37</td>
               <td>2011/06/02</td>
               <td>$95,400</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>32</td>
               <td>Suki Burks</td>
               <td>Developer</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>53</td>
               <td>2009/10/22</td>
               <td>$114,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>33</td>
               <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
               <td>Technical Author</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>27</td>
               <td>2011/05/07</td>
               <td>$145,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>34</td>
               <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
               <td>Team Leader</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>2008/10/26</td>
               <td>$235,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>35</td>
               <td>Martena Mccray</td>
               <td>Post-Sales support</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>46</td>
               <td>2011/03/09</td>
               <td>$324,050</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>36</td>
               <td>Unity Butler</td>
               <td>Marketing Designer</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>47</td>
               <td>2009/12/09</td>
               <td>$85,675</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>37</td>
               <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
               <td>Office Manager</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>51</td>
               <td>2008/12/16</td>
               <td>$164,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>38</td>
               <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
               <td>Secretary</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>41</td>
               <td>2010/02/12</td>
               <td>$109,850</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>39</td>
               <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
               <td>Financial Controller</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>62</td>
               <td>2009/02/14</td>
               <td>$452,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>40</td>
               <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
               <td>Office Manager</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>37</td>
               <td>2008/12/11</td>
               <td>$136,200</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>41</td>
               <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
               <td>Director</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>65</td>
               <td>2008/09/26</td>
               <td>$645,750</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>42</td>
               <td>Olivia Liang</td>
               <td>Support Engineer</td>
               <td>Singapore</td>
               <td>64</td>
               <td>2011/02/03</td>
               <td>$234,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>43</td>
               <td>Bruno Nash</td>
               <td>Software Engineer</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>38</td>
               <td>2011/05/03</td>
               <td>$163,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>44</td>
               <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
               <td>Support Engineer</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>37</td>
               <td>2009/08/19</td>
               <td>$139,575</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>45</td>
               <td>Thor Walton</td>
               <td>Developer</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>61</td>
               <td>2013/08/11</td>
               <td>$98,540</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>46</td>
               <td>Finn Camacho</td>
               <td>Support Engineer</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>47</td>
               <td>2009/07/07</td>
               <td>$87,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>47</td>
               <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
               <td>Data Coordinator</td>
               <td>Singapore</td>
               <td>64</td>
               <td>2012/04/09</td>
               <td>$138,575</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>48</td>
               <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
               <td>Software Engineer</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>63</td>
               <td>2010/01/04</td>
               <td>$125,250</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>49</td>
               <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
               <td>Software Engineer</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>56</td>
               <td>2012/06/01</td>
               <td>$115,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>50</td>
               <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
               <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>43</td>
               <td>2013/02/01</td>
               <td>$75,650</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>51</td>
               <td>Cara Stevens</td>
               <td>Sales Assistant</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>46</td>
               <td>2011/12/06</td>
               <td>$145,600</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>52</td>
               <td>Hermione Butler</td>
               <td>Regional Director</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>47</td>
               <td>2011/03/21</td>
               <td>$356,250</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>53</td>
               <td>Lael Greer</td>
               <td>Systems Administrator</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>21</td>
               <td>2009/02/27</td>
               <td>$103,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>54</td>
               <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
               <td>Developer</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>30</td>
               <td>2010/07/14</td>
               <td>$86,500</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>55</td>
               <td>Shad Decker</td>
               <td>Regional Director</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>51</td>
               <td>2008/11/13</td>
               <td>$183,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>56</td>
               <td>Michael Bruce</td>
               <td>Javascript Developer</td>
               <td>Singapore</td>
               <td>29</td>
               <td>2011/06/27</td>
               <td>$183,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>57</td>
               <td>Donna Snider</td>
               <td>Customer Support</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>27</td>
               <td>2011/01/25</td>
               <td>$112,000</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>

    <p>Press <b>Submit</b> and check console for URL-encoded form data that would be submitted.</p>

    <p><button>Submit</button></p>

    <b>Data submitted to the server:</b><br>


    </form>

    <pre id="printarr"></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can any one help me with this

Comment: That's a lot of code :-)  Not sure I understand the issue.  Are you trying to create a select all checkbox?

Comment: yes iis created but working only for current page

Comment: Take a look at the [Gyrocode Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plugin for Datatables.  It is easy to implement and has a check all option.